# Current location in Google Maps and storing the received location on TextView

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, textview, android-location

I'm new to android and working through many tutorials to get users current location with autozoom and storing that location Latitude and Longitude to a text view. So far I'm not able to get Location and getting continuous errors and crash. Same time I can't able to show the status of gpsStatus and networkConnectionStatus. I'm working with targetSDKlevel 23.

Answers are Appriciated.

## Heres the code

```
public class Maps extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;

public TextView tvRescueLocation;


void error()
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready   to be used.
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    tvRescueLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRescueLocation);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
        builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                Intent intent = new   Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    setMap();
}

public void setMap() {
    try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                        (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            //Set map type to TERRAIN
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

            //Remapping the position of Location button
            mMap.setPadding(0, 800, 0, 0);

            //Enable UI controls of Map
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)   getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
            Location newLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            location(newLoc);
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        error();
    }
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

public void location(Location location) {
    final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .draggable(true)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_location_flag)))
            .setSnippet("Rescue Location - CLICK HERE");


    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom
            (latLng, 17));

    //Adding Custom Circle for Rescue Attention
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center(latLng)
            .radius(40)
            .strokeWidth(3)
            .strokeColor(Color.RED);
    mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

}
```

}

LogCat:

```
04-01 15:40:29.334 22356-22675/? W/ActivityThread: ClassLoader.loadClass:     The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for     processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a     context class loader. For example:     Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
04-01 15:40:29.490 22356-22356/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 154 frames!  The     application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-01 15:40:29.709 22655-22659/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 732K, 22%     free 4617K/5912K, paused 5ms+10ms, total 43ms
04-01 15:40:29.709 22655-22655/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 38ms
04-01 15:40:29.724 22356-22356/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-01 15:40:29.724 22356-22356/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with     uncaught exception (group=0x41701ba8)
04-01 15:40:29.771 22356-22356/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.rescue,     PID: 22356
                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at     com.rescue.Maps.location(Maps.java:159)
                                                   at     com.rescue.Maps.setMap(Maps.java:125)
                                                   at     com.rescue.Maps.onMapReady(Maps.java:95)
                                                   at     com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at     com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                   at     android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
                                                   at     com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.v$a$a.a(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:82)
                                                   at     maps.ei.bu$6.run(Unknown Source)
                                                   at     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                   at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                   at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
                                                   at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                   at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 15:40:29.795 435-707/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity     com.rescue/.Maps
```

Comment: check `logcat` output for more details about crash!

Comment: I'm just going through the logcat but there is no such errors showing. Once I was able to get the location but for testing I off the GPS and network from that time I'm not getting location only getting exception error. Is there any chance to NOT use .getLastKnownLocation, with instead of any other in SDK level 23.

Comment: which device you are testing

Comment: I'm testing on galaxy nexus (4.4.4).

Answer (score 0):

Use **LocationManager**

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();

//Now set the value of Double to String
String Lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
String Lon = String.valueOf(longitude);

//Set value to textview

YourTextView1.setText(Lat);
YourTextView2.setText(Lon);
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting NullPointException, please go through my previous comment for detail.

Comment: Have you given appropriate permissions in Manifest File?

Comment: yes <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

Comment: Post the output of Logcat so that we can figure out what exactly the error is.

Comment: Make sure you had your device gps turned on!! It may be a reason to return the null value

Comment: I tried adding a dialog to get the status of GPS and internet but It doesn't show me the status of GPS and internet.

Comment: try that method i have posted, hope it will not crash now

Comment: can you edit my code with the code that you have provided im little confused where to add the code(NOOB me).

Comment: add that on setMap() method, replace your locationmanager code with that ,
 
delete your code from setMap() method from location manager upto public void location(....)

Answer (score 0):

getLastKnownLocation() has the possibility of returning null which may cause your app to crash with a NullPointerException.

Alternatively, you can go over the Location Strategies docs provided by Android and use the method provided there:

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager 
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)          this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Define a listener that responds to location updates 
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() { 
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    // Display a marker on the GoogleMap
} 
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {} 
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {} 
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {} 
}; 
// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
// NOTE : PLEASE ADJUST THE FREQUENCY OF UPDATES PROPERLY
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: add that on setMap() method, replace your locationmanager code with that

Comment: delete your code from setMap() method from location manager upto public void location(....)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work properly, It do start the Map but there is no any functions(No AutoZoom, Markers nothing).

Comment: that is because you have defined that all in location method. have you called that method from setMap()?

Comment: Yes, and only Maps starts but no other functions.

Comment: Add all that function on setMap()